# Mysql query using order by and group by clause for highest qualification

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, group-by

I want to get user highest education details in descending order instead of all education details, so I am joining user table  with education details table, but query which I written using group by and order by clause even it is not working as per my expectation.

```
 table  users:
    
    id   name
    
    1    aaa
    
    2    bbb
    
    3    ccc
```

table  education_details

```
    eid  user_id   course_id    course type
    
    1    1        12           graduation
    
    2    1        13           post_graduation
    
    3    2        18           graduation
    
    4    2        20           post_graduation
```

Expected output:

```
user_id   eid             course_type

2          4             post_graduation

1          2             post_graduation
```

Query:

```
$this->db->select('u.id as user_id,e.eid,e.course_type');
$this->db->from('users u');
$this->db->join('education_details e','e.user_id=u.id','left');
$this->db->order_by('e.id','desc');
$this->db->group_by('e.user_id');
$this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: how do you identify highest qualification for a user?

Comment: I am simply inserting in table via array  and last element in education details will be highest qualification so checking last inserted record

Comment: in raw SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql